# Application Insights picks up SQL telemetry locally but not in a real environment

Tags: azure-application-insights

Generally I've had pretty good luck with Application Insights' auto-detection of a SQL dependency.  However, in a recent case where we added Application Insights to a Web API project, we are not seeing dependency tracking for SQL Server in the portal.  Version info:

```
 Application Insights 2.5.0
 Entity Framework 6.x
 .NET 4.5.2
```

The funny thing is that Azure *will* automatically pick up SQL calls when developers are using the debugger from Visual Studio.  What do we need to do to capture timings for SQL calls on a real environment?

Thanks,
BGU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the Web API project to a more recent version of .NET (4.6 or higher).  Good luck out there.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now

Dependency diagnostics like full sql command text will be available in Application insights only at runtime. If web api project is hosted on IIS server, then try integrating your web application virtual directory to app insights resource using status monitor. Once you do that, it will push full sql command text to d app insights portal.[Comparison Build time and run time integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkv6n.png)